# Dual ABI support in a single file library? What's the easiest/best practice way?

Tags: c++11, cmake

- How can we compile a shared library to support both ABIs in a single .so file using Modern CMake (>3.4)?

If this is not possible, what's the best practice for that? I'd like to avoid hard-coded and custom code to keep the maintenance straightforward.

I found this link but it requires to change the code and uses gcc only: http://kayari.org/cxx/dualabi.html

**Reason:** My users have Centos 7 (old ABI exclusively) and Centos 8 (both ABI). The size of the library isn't important as long as the performance doesn't change.

*Targets: gcc and cmake*

Comment: Conveniently, Jason Turner just posted a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By7b19YIv8Q) about C++ and legacy ABI compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the video. I don't want C wrapper at all, it requires more work and defeats the purpose of using C++. Also, my users wanna use directly C++ header with C++ types. My question is for simplicity rather than a real problem. (providing a single file instead of 2)

Comment: I don't think you can get around changing the code here. Things like version scripts only apply when linking a whole shared library and AFAIK, they can't suppress symbols from individual object files.

Comment: Unfortunately yes and I found about it's more complicated than that. There are the `std lib abi version(cxx11)` but also the `language abi version` (CXXABI/GLIBCXX) that can still be incompatible.